# Cell shading, Can EEVEE do well with NPR like BI?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, npr

[image]

Hello.

I am interested in making NPR styles with Blender.

The nodes in BI are really intuitive to create cell shading.

I can use the shader's light and dark borders as a masking factor, and I can specify each color directly like the gif above.

But I know BI will disappear from Blender when EEVEE is complete.

Can EEVEE do well with NPR like BI?

Comment: Try it and see, you can download [recent test builds from here](https://builder.blender.org/download). If it doesn't work the way you want it would be better to make suggestions to the developers now rather than after it is released.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work.
How do i suggest my opinion to developers now?

Comment: See the [contact developers page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact), there is a mailing list specifically for the 2.8 viewport and one for npr. Suggestions can also be submitted to [rightclickselect](http://rightclickselect.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I've tried a bit and it really doesn't support the basic cel shading I do. You might contact SageLightBWK on BlenderNPR. He's been in contact with Ton about an NPR engine and is looking for coders.

Answer (score 0):

Something to look forward to in the future is the Python GLSL nodes for Eevee: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/Source/Viewport/PyNodeGLSL

Similar to what you can already do with [OSL and Cycles on CPU mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html), this node type will allow you to write (mostly) any shader formulas you want, including NPR (different shadow and light colours etc.)